# Application Exception When Using ODP.NET To Access An Oracle 12c Database

Tags: connection, runtime-error, app-config, oracle12c, odp.net

I am experiencing the following error exception when running my database application:

'The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.'
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section oracle.dataaccess.client.

I have been using the same technique for handling Oracle Collection User Defined Types (UDTs) for a number of years but after upgrading to Oracle 12c, I get the above message when simply trying to open an Oracle connection.

Relevant Information:

1) Visual Studio 2017

2) Oracle 12c Release 2 (This is the only Oracle software on my development system)

3) Development CPU: AMD Phenom

4) Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) Clean Install

5) Language: VB.NET

6) Oracle.DataAccess (4.122.1.0 - 64 bit) There is only one copy of this .dll on my development CPU. (I have confirmed that there is no copy in the GAC)
This is an unmanaged dll; I would love to use the managed version but Oracle has not included the interfaces that I need to handle UDTs in the managed version.

7) My application runs without error if the app.config file is not present.

8) I have provided a "bare bones" app example with an app.config file
(Like the complete app, it runs without error with no configuration file but     fails when the config file is present)

8) The settings section of the config file is an example of the 12c SYSTEM UDT implementation, but this mini-app fails with the same error message even if the UDT section is omitted.

9) Target CPU: x64

10) Simple Code Example And Configuration File:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '
    Dim cn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    '
    ' Change the following to your connection string        
    Dim cs As String = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=system;  Password=myOraclePW;"
   '
    cn.ConnectionString = cs
    '
    cn.Open()
    '
    MessageBox.Show("Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection Open")
    '
    cn.Close()
    '
End Sub

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <configuration>

  <startup>        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup>

  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings><add name="OraSYSTEM.SYSTEM.AQ$_QUEUES.AQ$_SUBSCRIBERS" 
               value="udtMapping factoryName='myApp.ListFactory_1, myApp' typeName='AQ$_SUBSCRIBERS' schemaName='userPW' dataSource='SYSTEM'"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>

</configuration>
```

This is the first time that I have submitted a problem to an on-line forum so I am hoping for the best! I believe that something has changed since Oracle 11g and/or Visual Studio 2010 and that I am not doing something to accommodate these changes, but for the life of me I don't know what it is. (I'm hoping that it is something small and/or stupid that I have overlooked but I have run out of "try this" ideas)

Thank you for any help and best regards,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

1/28/2018 Update:

Problem Solved!!!!

Like I figured, it was "something small and stupid".
The solution was using the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from the Instant Client (64 bit) install rather than the one in the database install. I was thrown off by having my app run successfully without the app.config file and using the database install .dll. 
I am still not sure why only the managed version of ODP.NET was installed in the GAC and not the unmanaged version when I installed the Instant Client (and ODAC).
At any rate, with the GAC load precedent over the local app version, I should be covered in either case.

Hope this might save someone else some time and anguish.

Greg